# Duvida com o AndroidPlot

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Pessoal alguem poderia me dizer porque este codigo não esta gerando o gráfico desejado?

//codigo da tela

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import com.androidplot.Plot;
import com.androidplot.xy.BoundaryMode;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYStepMode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class TelaB extends Activity {

        //Vetor de culturas da comboBox;
        private String[] culturas = new String[] {"Milho"};
        //Cria um objeto do XYPlot grafico  
        private static XYPlot grafico;

        //Vetor de dias da semana que sera colocado no grafico
        final static String[] dias = new String[]{"Dom","Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_telab);
            //pega o comboBox pelo id
            final Spinner combo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.comboCultura);
            //Cria um arrayAdapter
            ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, culturas);
            adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            //Set o ArrayAdapter no Spinner
            combo.setAdapter(adaptador);
            //Listener do Spinner
            combo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                //Se selecionado algo
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    //Fazer algo com isso;

                }
                //Se não
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        // pego o RadioGroup pelo id
        final RadioGroup dados = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.dados);
        //pega o Grafico pelo id
        grafico = (XYPlot)findViewById(R.id.grafico);
        //Listener do RadioGroup
        dados.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            //Cria booleans para testar os Radios se estão setados
            boolean temp = R.id.temp == checkedId;
            boolean umid = R.id.umid == checkedId;
            boolean pres = R.id.pres == checkedId;
            boolean alt = R.id.alt == checkedId;
            boolean umids = R.id.alt == checkedId;
            boolean vento = R.id.vento == checkedId;
            boolean lum = R.id.lum == checkedId;
            boolean temps = R.id.temps == checkedId;
            //Testes dos Boolean
            if(temp){
                //Seta os vetores com os dados
                Number[] dadoA = {27,29,24,26,30,29,28};
                Number[] dadoC = {24,30,24,30,24,30,24};
                //Nome que vai na lateral indicando o que é o grafico
                String nome = "Temperatura em ºC";
                //Chama o método que cria o gráfico
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(umid){
                Number[] dadoA = {};
                Number[] dadoC = {};
                String nome = "Umidade";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(pres){
                Number[] dadoA = {};
                Number[] dadoC = {};
                String nome = "Pressão";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(alt){
                Number[] dadoA = {};
                Number[] dadoC = {};
                String nome = "Altitude";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(umids){
                Number[] dadoA = {0.2,0.4,4,6,6,7,4};
                Number[] dadoC = {0.3,0.2,3,7,3,7,3};
                String nome = "Umidade do solo /mm";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(vento){
                Number[] dadoA = {};
                Number[] dadoC = {};
                String nome = "Velocidade do vento";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(lum){
                Number[] dadoA = {};
                Number[] dadoC = {};
                String nome = "Luminosidade";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }else if(temps){
                Number[] dadoA = {};
                Number[] dadoC = {};
                String nome = "Temperatura do solo";
                TelaB.grafico(dadoA, dadoC, nome);
            }

        }
    });


    }

    //Metodo que gera o gráfico
    public static void grafico(Number[] dadoA, Number[] dadoC, String nome){

        //Converte os arrays em uma série XY
        XYSeries Agri_Weather = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(dadoA), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,"DadoAgri_Weather");
        XYSeries Cultura = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(dadoC), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,"DadoCultura");

        //Cria um formato de linha e ponto
        LineAndPointFormatter Agri_Weather_Formato = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0,0,255),Color.rgb(200,200,200), null, null);
        LineAndPointFormatter Cultura_Formato = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0,0,255),Color.rgb(200,200,200), null, null);

        //Adiciona Agri_Weather e Cultura ao XYplot
        grafico.addSeries(Agri_Weather, Agri_Weather_Formato);
        grafico.addSeries(Cultura, Cultura_Formato);

        //Formata o DomainValues X-Axis
        grafico.setDomainValueFormat(new Format(){
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos){
                return new StringBuffer(dias[((Number)obj).intValue()]);
            }
            @Override
            public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos){
                return null;
            }

        });

        grafico.setDomainLabel("");
        grafico.setRangeLabel(nome);

        //Incrementa o X-Axis em 1
        grafico.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 1);
        grafico.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelWidth(25);

        //Reduz o numero de range labels
        grafico.setTicksPerRangeLabel(2);

        //Reduz o numero de domain labels
        grafico.setTicksPerDomainLabel(2);

    }
}
```

//Layout da tela

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/comboCultura"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dados"
            >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temperatura" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/umid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Umidade" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/pres"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pressão" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/alt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Altitude" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/umids"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Umidade do solo" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/vento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Velocidade do vento" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Luminosidade" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/temps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temperatura do solo" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
    android:id="@+id/grafico"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    title="Gráfico meteorologico"/>
```

O tipo de gráfico desejado é o de linha, sendo que nos dias da semana (que foi colocado no código) do segmento X no gráfico deve-se colocar pontos para destacar nas linhas.

A parte que há problema é na do AndroidPlot, mais expecificamente no método grafico do código, pois os valores estão sendo passados corretamente, mas quando rodo no emulador ele não gera gráfico nenhum ao clicar nos Spinners.

Obrigado

Comment: Olá Lucas, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor especifique melhor seu problema: qual é o "gráfico desejado", e que parte do código não está funcionando como deveria? Sugiro [edit] sua pergunta para deixá-la mais focada.

Comment: Olá. Sendo mais especifico, o gráfico desejado é um gráfico de linhas, com pontos que referenciem os dias da semana (colocados no código). A parte que não está funcionando é a do androidPlot, o resto está ok, e sei que na função grafico os valores estão sendo passados nos vetores corretamente, o problema é gerar, já que quando rodo no emulador ele não aparece quando clico no radio button. Obrigado pela ajuda